# parse_edgelist with duplicates to a weighted network? python networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have wrote some code to import an edgelist from a .txt file I have for some Twitter relationship data.  The data is directed and includes duplicate values.  I would like to load this data into a `DiGraph()` with the edge weight included, but I can't figure that part out.  I was thinking about using something like `Counter()` to count the duplicate edges, but I'm not sure how to take that count and include that in the graph.

I've included a sample of the .txt file to show what my data will look like.

**Sample .txt Data**

```
# twitter data
# retrieved at: 07.08.2014
# total number of records: 8
# exported by: userXYZ
#
# fields: date, time, source, target
10.12.2013; 02:00; tweeterA; tweeterB
10.12.2013; 02:01; tweeterB; tweeterC
10.13.2013; 02:04; tweeterC; tweeterA
10.13.2013; 02:08; tweeterC; tweeterA
10.13.2013; 02:10; tweeterD; tweeterB
10.13.2013; 02:11; tweeterA; tweeterC
10.13.2013; 02:13; tweeterC; tweeterB
10.13.2013; 02:18; tweeterA; tweeterD
```

**Existing Code**

```
import networkx as nx

header = ['date', 'time', 'source', 'target']

data = [{key: value for (key, value) in zip(header, line.strip().split('; '))} for line in open('data.txt') if not line.startswith('#')]

edgelist = []
for i in data:
    edgelist.append(" ".join([
    i['source'],
    i['target']]))

G = nx.parse_edgelist(edgelist,create_using=nx.DiGraph())

nx.draw(G)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close, I think, and yes you can use `collections.Counter()`. Then you need to associate the weights with each edge by setting the weight as a data attribute.

```
from collections import Counter
import networkx as nx

edge_counts = Counter((' '.join(line.strip().split('; ')[2:]) for line in open('data.txt') if not line.startswith('#')))

G = nx.parse_edgelist(('%s %d' % edge for edge in edge_counts.items()),
                      data=(('weight',int),),
                      create_using=nx.DiGraph())

# nx.draw(G)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(sorted(G.edges(data=True)))
```

Should give you this output:

```
[('tweeterA', 'tweeterB', {'weight': 1}),
 ('tweeterA', 'tweeterC', {'weight': 1}),
 ('tweeterA', 'tweeterD', {'weight': 1}),
 ('tweeterB', 'tweeterC', {'weight': 1}),
 ('tweeterC', 'tweeterA', {'weight': 2}),
 ('tweeterC', 'tweeterB', {'weight': 1}),
 ('tweeterD', 'tweeterB', {'weight': 1})]
```